# build multi tenant application with jdo google app engine

Tags: google-app-engine, gwt, jdo, datanucleus

I want to build multi tenant application.
I build application with gwt.
my server side run on google app engine and my data base is jdo datanucleus
if possible to create data base per tenant? if yes how I can do this?
if is not possible how i can build multi tenant application?
sorry on my english
thank you

Comment: How many tenants are you going to have and how bad would it be if data leaked between silos? If the numbers low and/or security needs to be high maybe give them each their own gae instance? Then the multi tenancy would be done for you and you could do nice things like roll out new software versions on customer at a time?

Comment: First of all thanks for the response
I started with the construction of an application for each tenant but it was not suitable for the application service provides so I have to go through one application service providers to tenants
I start with three tenants but later I will probably several dozen more.
Level of safety is very important and should not leak information from a tenant to tenant.
Thank you

Comment: That is a shame as it is not an easy thing to do. I've not used these technologies before so can't advise much more. All I can say is I'd strongly suggest you do it at a very deep level of your app. On our current project with oracle we set a context value on each db connection and then row and cell filter in db views. That you don't have to worry about every line of application code.

Answer (score 1):

Didn't try this myself but I sugges to look here: https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/multitenancy/ for the recommended way of multi-tenancy by Google on AppEngine.

Comment: first for all thank you for reply I saw this article and I read it but I not understand how to use in namespace api thank you